# Upgrade to SharePoint 2013

Tags: upgrade

I have a very simple question.

I need to upgrade my SharePoint 2010 to SharePoint 2013. I saw the documentation.

Does it mean that a need a new machine for SP2013 and another SQL rather than the existing one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Microsoft, for SharePoint 2013, the only upgrade method is the database-attach upgrade method, which means you have to set up a new SharePoint 2013 environment rather than using an existing one.

More information can be found on [Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262747.aspx)

Comment: Yes i read that too. In my case, single server, what if i unsintall SP2010 and install SP2013. Would not this do the work?

Comment: If the migration to 2013 fails or does not succeed the first try, you wouldn't have the 2010 system to revert back to.

Comment: Also, you need service applications, configurations and content databases in old 2010 farm as a reference to your new 2013 environment.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need a new machine for the new SharePoint 2013 farm, and preferably a new one for SQL.
/WW